# Error while parsing and storing xml data in database using jstl tags

Tags: xml, jsp, parsing, jstl

I have to read an xml file, display its content in the form of a table and need to store the data in database table. Firstly I tried to only display the data using jstl1.2 tags in my jsp. It is working fine. But when I tried to implement some code to insert the records I am getting this error..

```
 Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.JSTLNodeList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

My Jsp code is as:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
     url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" user="postgres" password="shail"
     scope="session" />

<html>
  <head>
    <title>cust_xml</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Customer Information</h1>

    <c:import var="xmlFile" url="cust.xml"  charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <x:parse var="myDoc" xml="${xmlFile}" />

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Customer Number</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      <x:forEach select="$myDoc/CUSTOMERS/Customer" var="cust">
        <tr>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustNo" />
              <x:set var="custno" select="$cust/CustNo" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustFirstName" />
              <x:set var="custfn" select="$cust/CustFirstName" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustLastName" />
              <x:set var="custln" select="$cust/CustLastName" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustStreet" />
              <x:set var="custst" select="$cust/CustStreet" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustCity" />
              <x:set var="custcity" select="$cust/CustCity" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustState" />
              <x:set var="custstate" select="$cust/CustState" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustZip" />
              <x:set var="custz" select="$cust/CustZip" scope="session"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustBal" />
              <x:set var="custbal" select="$cust/CustBal" scope="session"/>
             </td>
        </tr>
      </x:forEach>
    </table>

    <sql:update dataSource="${dataSource}" var="updatedTable">
        INSERT INTO data  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
        <sql:param value="${custno}" />
        <sql:param value="${custfn}" />
        <sql:param value="${custln}" />
        <sql:param value="${custst}" />
        <sql:param value="${custcity}" />
        <sql:param value="${custstate}" />
        <sql:param value="${custz}" />
        <sql:param value="${custbal}" />
    </sql:update>
    <c:if test="${updatedTable>=1}">
     <font size="5" color='green'> Congratulations ! Data inserted successfully.</font>
    </c:if>

  </body>
</html>
```

Please provide your suggestion which tag shall I use to set the values to insert query parameters? How to get the xml elements data to set in query parameters?
Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please some one help me. I am googling for last 2-3 days. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried hard to get the solution of my problem but unfortunately  couldn't get any help.
While googling I got some basic idea to cope with this. I tried this

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
     url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" user="postgres" password="shail"
     scope="session" />

<html>
  <head>
    <title>cust_xml</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="skyblue">

    <h1 align="center">Customer Information Stored In XMl File</h1>

    <c:import var="xmlFile" url="cust.xml"  charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <x:parse var="myDoc" xml="${xmlFile}" />

    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="pink" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>Customer Number</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      <x:forEach select="$myDoc/CUSTOMERS/Customer" var="cust">
        <tr>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custno" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustNo" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustNo" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custfn" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustFirstName" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustFirstName" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custln" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustLastName" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustLastName" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custst" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustStreet" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustStreet" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custcity" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustCity" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustCity" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custstate" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustState" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustState" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custz" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustZip" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustZip" />
             </td>
             <td>
              <c:set var="custbal" >
              <x:out select="$cust/CustBal" />
              </c:set>
              <x:out select="$cust/CustBal" />
             </td>
        </tr>
        <sql:update dataSource="${dataSource}" var="updatedTable">
        INSERT INTO data  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
        <sql:param value="${custno}" />
        <sql:param value="${custfn}" />
        <sql:param value="${custln}" />
        <sql:param value="${custst}" />
        <sql:param value="${custcity}" />
        <sql:param value="${custstate}" />
        <sql:param value="${custz}" />
        <sql:param value="${custbal}" />

    </sql:update>
    <c:set var="rowcount" value="${updatedTable+rowcount}"/>
      </x:forEach>

    <c:if test="${rowcount>=1}">
      <tr>
       <td colspan="8" align="center">
     <font size="5" color='red' align="center">
     Congratulations ! <c:out value="${rowcount}" /> Rows inserted successfully  in DB Table.</font>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </c:if>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I got this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
        INSERT INTO data  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
ERROR: column "balance" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

As in my table balance(last column) is integer type.
When I googled I got that jstl tags automatically take care of casting. But it is showing error as `by default <c:set > tag places value for variable as string.`
Any idea? Any help? Any suggestion? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the `?` with `CAST` function and still use `setObject()` method.
Let me give you an example
While storing IP address in **MySQL** my query use to be like this

```
INSERT INTO log (ip,logged_on) VALUES(inet6_aton(?),no());
```

PS: `inet6_aton()` for MySQL 5.6+ else use `inet4_aton()` or just `inet_aton()`

Now I shifted to **Postgres** and it doesn't have `inet_aton` function but `inet` as a datatype. Unfortunately, there is not `setInet()` method so I'd to do this

```
INSERT INTO log (ip,looged_on) VALUES(CAST(? AS INET),now());
```

With this I can use `setString()` or `setObject()` while passing the parameters in `JDBC` or with `JSTL`

> INSERT INTO data  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);

Since you haven't mentioned the column names like I did in my example I don't know which of the column needs to be typecast but you can try by writing it like this

```
 INSERT INTO data VALUES (CAST(? AS INTEGER),?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

I'm just assuming the first column of your table as `balance` please do this for the appropriate parameter depending upon the position of `balance` column in your table.