# How to parse xml file which is in directory?

Tags: java, xml

can you please tell me how to parse xml file in java .
Hi Have an xml file I want to print all author and title of every elemet .

I done like that but not got any success .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>

</catalog>
```

I do like this ..

```
private class Connection extends Thread {
    private String element;
    public Connection() {
        super();
    }
    public void run() {
        StreamConnection conn;
        String str=null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            docBuilder.isValidating();
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a.xml");

            Document document = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("catalog");
            element = new String();
            // this "for" loop is used to parse through the
            // XML document and extract all elements and their
            // value, so they can be displayed on the device
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                Node value = list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
                element = value.getNodeValue();
                synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {

                    add(new RichTextField("Title : " + element));
                 add(new SeparatorField());
                }
            }// end for
                                      //      screen.add(new RichTextField(str));
        }// end try
            // will catch any exception thrown by the XML parser
        catch (Exception e) {
           add(new RichTextField("Error : " + e.toString()));
        }
    }// end connection function
}// end connection class


connection = new Connection();
connection.start();//
```

Comment: show us what you have done.

Comment: and say why it does not work!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354466/updating-an-xml-string

see if it helps!

Comment: I already written by code here

Comment: OP included code, but didn't separate it from his XML. Now it should be more visible.

Comment: Is the file in a directory on the file system or embedded within your application context?

Comment: there is no exception..like file not found

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090007/error-while-parsing-and-storing-xml-data-in-database-using-jstl-tags/15108264#15108264)
I have done this job last year, let me know for any other issues. You can specify your path to file in `url="cust.xml"` portion . It is done in Jsp but better if you do this all in  Action class(In case of using Struts) or in Servlet program.

For a better way to do this refer [this link](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/20574-read-XML-file-and-display-it-using-java-servlets.html)

Answer (score 0):

XPath is probably the most straightforward here. Give this a go...

Test.java

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("file:///C:/path/to/books.xml");
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book/author|//book/title");
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println(currentNode.getTextContent());
        }
    }

  }

}
```

javac -classpath jaxp-api-1.4.jar Test.java

java Test

```
Gambardella, Matthew
XML Developer's Guide
Ralls, Kim
Midnight Rain
Corets, Eva
Maeve Ascendant
Corets, Eva
Oberon's Legacy
Corets, Eva
The Sundered Grail
Randall, Cynthia
Lover Birds
Thurman, Paula
Splish Splash
Knorr, Stefan
Creepy Crawlies
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is that you are selecting `catalog` instead of `book` as `NodeList`. This way your list will have only one element instead of 8. Try maybe with this code (I print output to console but you can use it whatever you like)

```
NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("book");
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList childs = list.item(i).getChildNodes();

    //iterate over all child nodes like author/title/description
    for (int j = 0; j < childs.getLength(); j++) {
        Node child = childs.item(j);
        //if node is the one we are looking for print it
        if (child.getNodeName().equals("author"))
            System.out.println("author : "+child.getTextContent());
        if (child.getNodeName().equals("title"))
            System.out.println("title : "+child.getTextContent());
    }
    System.out.println("------------");//
}// end for
```

---

Another approach would be using some other parsers. I like Jsoup which is mainly used to parse HTML but it also have XML parser. its code could look like this

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

...

    InputStream xml = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "utf-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
    for (Element e : doc.select("book author, book title")) {
        System.out.println(e.nodeName() + ": " + e.text());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a handle to the catalog node. The following line in your code gets first child from the list of all child nodes under catalog node. It will point to the first book node.

```
Node value = list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
```

The value of this node is blank as this is not a text node. You need to get a handle to the title node and then print its value. You can do that by getting a list of all book nodes and then get to the title node. Note that the index for title node is 2 as index 0 will be the attribute node for book element.

```
NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("book");
        element = new String();
        // this "for" loop is used to parse through the
        // XML document and extract all elements and their
        // value, so they can be displayed on the device
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Element thisNode = (Element)list.item(i);
            Node value = (Node)(list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(2));
            System.out.println(value.getTextContent() +"-");                

        }// end for
```

I do not recommend that you use this approach. Better way is to use XPath as previously answered or you can use JAXB, in case you are updating the data and regenerating XML.